# Use of $? in a bash function

Tags: bash, return-value

I am having a problem with testing `$?` within a function, regardless of how it is passed.

```
__myretval () {
  if [ $1 -ne 0 ]; then
    printf -- "%s" "$1"
  fi
}
PS1="$(__myretval '$?') $"
```

The goal being to have retvals show if they not 0.  The function is MUCH more detailed than this and it must be in the function, please do not suggest pulling this out of the function.

```
$ false
1 $ true
$
```

I have tried every combination I can think of, but nothing seems to work, including but not limited to combinations of the following.  I've tried putting the value in quotes, and without quotes; I've tried doing the same for the 0, with quotes and without.

```
if [ $1 -ne 0 ]; then
if [ $1 != 0 ]; then
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
PS1="$(__myretval "$?") $"
PS1="$(__myretval "\$?") $"
```

Either the value *always* prints or it *never* prints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
__myretval () {
  if (($1)); then
    printf -- "%s" "$1"
  fi
}
PS1='$(__myretval "$?") $'
```

It seems your problem was with the quotes.

---

When you state:

```
PS1="$(__myretval '$?') $"
```

what you're doing is (because of the double quotes): setting `PS1` to the output of the function `__myretval` with the argument `'$?'`, where `$?` is expanded *now*. So your `PS1` never changes.

What you want instead is `PS1` to contain the string:

```
$(__myretval "$?") $
```

so that this string is expanded (evaluated) at each new prompt. That's why you should use *single quotes* to define your `PS1`.

Comment: @jnovack it's equivalent in this case. In bash it's better to use double parentheses for arithmetic evaluation. `((var))` is true if and only if `var` doesn't expand to a nil value: it's sugar for `((var!=0))`. Your question being tagged Bash, I assumed you wanted a code in the best Bash style.

Comment: This is phenomenal, but does not scale to use bash variables.  This works, yes.  However, the function is more complex and thus PS variables do not expand. When adding in the standard [\u@\h], it does not work.  When adding in other variables (such as escaped colors), it does not work. :/

Comment: @jnovack what do you mean really? what is your function doing that you can't use this template?

Comment: @jnovack, the approach given here certainly works in the general case, so you'll need to provide a more specific failure case.

Comment: The rest of the function changes the scope of this question, so I'm accepting this as is, as you did answer the original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to alternate the use of single `'` and double `"` quotes to control when 
the contained expression and variables get evaluated.

Also, why pass `$?` as a parameter?  Add `local status=$?` as the *first* statement in the function, and you won't need any checks:

```
__myretval () {
  local status=$?
  [[ $status -eq 0 ]] && return

  echo $status
}
```

Also, because `$status` is now guaranteed to contain a valid string with no surprises, we won't need `printf`, as `$( ... )` will drop the final newline.

How you set `PS1` will require appropriate quoting:

```
PS1="${OTHER_VARIABLE}"'$(__myretval) $ '
```

Double quotes evaluate when PS1 gets set, single quotes postpone that.

Comment: This actually answers my NEXT question. How do I ALSO use PS BASH variables in PS1? Unfortunately I cannot accept BOTH as answers.  However, people reading this will want to find this answer as working as well.

Comment: +1 for seeing the bigger picture - not having to pass in `$?` from the outside.